# Where to find nice latex thesis templates like this

Tags: templates, thesis, themes

[Here](https://www.attoworld.de/fileadmin/user_upload/tx_attoworld/publications/thesis_phd_en_Y2015_M01_D15_LMU_FakPhys_FattahiHanieh.pdf) a phd thesis can be found which has a very nice template, structure, and features. Does anyone know where we can find similar or even nicer Latex templates like this one ?

Comment: The [one](https://www.matthiaspospiech.de/blog/2018/09/21/latex-thesis-template-3-2-5-released/) of [Matthias Pospiech](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/7978/matthias-pospiech) is the best I have ever found. It includes also a detailed documentation.

Comment: @Ñako thanks but it doesn't have the appealing visual aspects of the thesis remarked in my question.